# Write logic in setPositiveButton OnClickListener() of an AlertDialog

Tags: android

> Hi I wanna write some of my logic in onClickListeners of my positive button of AlertDialog
> my app has a signUp/Login page that when user click on signUp button in fisrt page an AlertDialog appear and i wanna to create an object of my User model and save that in my UserRepositoty but this code not works for me , glad to help  me .

### My SignUpDialogFragment code

```
public class SignUpDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

private EditText mEditTextUserName;
private EditText mEditTextPassword;
private EditText mEditTextRepeatPassword;
private UserRepository mUserRepository;


public SignUpDialogFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static SignUpDialogFragment newInstance() {
    SignUpDialogFragment fragment = new SignUpDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUserRepository = UserRepository.getInstance();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_up, null);
    findViews(view);

    return new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(R.string.sign_up)
            .setView(R.layout.fragment_sign_up)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.sign_up, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if (checkInputs()) {
                        User user = new User(mEditTextUserName.getText().toString(), mEditTextPassword.getText().toString());
                        mUserRepository.add(user);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), user.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
            .create();

}

private boolean checkInputs() {
    if (mEditTextUserName.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || mEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim().length() < 8
            || !mEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals(mEditTextRepeatPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wrong Inputs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void findViews(View view) {
    mEditTextUserName = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_signUp_userName);
    mEditTextPassword = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_signUp_password);
    mEditTextRepeatPassword = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_signUp_repeat_password);
    }
}
```

> when AlertDialog dismiss user.toString() that must show in Toast have no userName and Password that must be filled before .

Comment: Could you please explain more about your question.

Comment: my problem in onClick method of alertDialog positive button , when dialog close and dismiss my user object that i created in onClick have empty fields and dont have username and password.

Comment: show what is `User` and `UserRepository` (models)

Answer (score 0):

i found my problem
my mistake in setView() method for my AlertDialog i must write setView(view) not setView(R.layout.fragment_sign_up)

### Correct code is there

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_up, null);
findViews(view);

return new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getActivity())
        .setTitle(R.string.sign_up)
        .setView(view)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.sign_up, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if (checkInputs()) {
                    User user = new User(mEditTextUserName.getText().toString(), mEditTextPassword.getText().toString());
                    mUserRepository.add(user);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), user.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
        .create();
```

}